# Tkinter: self.pack() causes error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I wrote my first Tkinter app that contains a button which, on clicking, is supposed to display an image in a canvas:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import numpy as np
from itertools import cycle

import helpers


class App():

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = tk.Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(width=500, height=500)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.load_button = tk.Button(
            frame, text="Load image", command=self.load_image)
        self.load_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.img_no = 0

    def load_image(self):
        stack = helpers.read_image_sequence("path")
        data = stack[self.img_no]
        im = Image.fromarray(data)
        im = im.resize((200, 200))
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=im)
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor=tk.NW)
        self.pack()


root = tk.Tk()

app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
```

After clicking the button, the image won't appear unless I add `self.pack()` at the end of its function. This works but causes the error:

```
AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'pack'
```

Apparently this is because my App() class doesn't inherit from a suitable parent. How to do this properly? I tried `tk.Tk` as parent:

```
class App(tk.Tk):

def __init__(self, master):
    super().__init__()
```

Which results in the error:

```
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'pack'
```

And I tried `tk.Frame` which doesn't result in any error, but the image doesn't show either! What am I missing..? Using Python 3.5.

Comment: sure u need specify what u want back, self refer only to instance attribute but self without anything is not referring to any elements; if you notice before you did self.canvas.pack() and worked without problems

Comment: Why do you think you need `self.pack()`? You've packed all widgets and you class is not a widget, so you don't need to (and can't) pack it. The reason you're not seeing the image is because it is garbage collected. Change `photo` to `self.photo` and you should be good. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function/16424553#16424553) and [here](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm).

Comment: @fhdrsdg Thanks, that did it! It's quite simple, intuitively I thought I needed to `pack` the GUI to update it, as I've seen before in other frameworks in similar ways. And using `self.pack()` did work, the image showed up! It's probably though because the exception it caused hindered garbage collection...

Comment: `It's probably though because the exception it caused hindered garbage collection` Exactly, the exception was raised before the function returned! When you see `pack` called on a class, it's usually a class that inherits from `tk.Frame`. If you do that, you can use `self` as the master of all widgets and `pack` the frame in your `Tk` instance either from inside or outside the class.

Comment: By the way, when you call `self.canvas = tk.Canvas(width=500, height=500)`, the canvas is placed in `root`, not in your `frame`, because you didn't specify the master. That's why your button is put above your canvas now.